# MiniMagick and Carrierwave not resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

Using Rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.2
I simply want to use carrierwave/minimagick as so:

In my Gemfile

```
 gem 'carrierwave'
 gem 'mini_magick'
```

In my uploader

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mini_magick' 
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
   include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
   include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:

  def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end

  process :resize_to_fit => [800, 800]

    version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_fit => [200,200]
    end

    version :mini do
       process :resize_to_fit => [50,50]
     end

    version :medium do
      process :resize_to_fit => [250,250]
    end

  def extension_white_list 
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png) 
   end
end
```

The problem is that the thumb, mini and medium versions are saving itself properly but not resizing (the size is the same for all versions).

anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: Are you using Heroku or some other non-write filesystem by chance?

Comment: Hey tyler, thanks for your help. I'm on localhost for now but will be on a vps after that.

Comment: hmmm just realized that minimagick doesn't even resize when i call the function separately: image = MiniMagick::Image.open("4.jpg") and
  image.resize "10x10"

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured it out.... after 4 hours of debugging!

I was using ruby 1.9.2 that was not compatible with the resizing of minimagick
Once I upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 everything went back to normal and resizing worked perfectly.

This should be clearly documented.