# CarrierWave not resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave with ImageSorcery in order to handle image uploads and thumbs creation.
Everything worked really well until I realized my thumbs were saved without being resized =/

I don't know what causes this and didn't find any solution working for me on the interwebs.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p247 and here's my code :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'thin'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails', '~> 0.4.9'

gem 'image_sorcery'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-imagesorcery'

gem 'unicode_utils'
gem 'protected_attributes'

gem "font-awesome-rails"

group :development, :test do
    gem 'meta_request'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'pry'
end
```

The uploader :

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::ImageSorcery

    storage :file

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_limit => [210, 222]
    end

    def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end
end
```

I have already found posts like [MiniMagick and Carrierwave not resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299883/minimagick-and-carrierwave-not-resizing) but none answered my problem :/

If anyone has an idea or had the same problem I'd be really glad to discuss it.

Thanks :)

Comment: any reason why you use ImageSorcery instead of RMagick? - I have a similar uploader but with "include CarrierWave::RMagick" and it works fine..

Comment: It seems to be way lighter than RMagick. but switching back to rmagick just works, so ...

But still, I'd like to find where the bug is =/

Comment: can you try :resize_to_fit instead of : resize_to_limit?

Comment: Not sure that would resolve the problem.

I switched back to rmagick and everything is working.